# How do I check if all fields are filled in

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

How would I check if certain fields are incomplete?

I want it so that whenever somebody clicks my button called "ADD?" that a messagebox will appear if required fields have not been properly filled out.

Comment: You can't do that in the event handler of the _ADD_ button?

Comment: As a side note - In this forum its not necessary to write the things like this `Please Can somebody answer this one. Just this ONE!! I promise`.

Comment: @seldon - I don't think its a question that he / she cannot, its a question of how to.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  I have a feeling the reason your begging us to answer this question is because your past questions have been closed because they were vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your event handler for the "Add" button, just check to see if the "field" has been filled in, and if not, don't continue:

```
void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxField.Text))
    {
         // Show message?
         MessageBox.Show(....);

         return; // Don't process
    }

    // Field has a value, do your thing here...

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [errorprovider component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95ysxkwy.aspx), or simply check the input text length if it is 0 throw up a message

```
If (myTextBox.Text.Length == 0)
 {
   //throw up message box
   MessageBox.Show("You forgot to fill in this field!");
   return;
 }
```